# Detecting distribution peaks and their significance

Tags: distributions, gaussian-mixture-distribution, mixture-distribution, mode, circular-statistics

I have (a lot of) datasets with points having 1d distributions like these:[image: example histograms]
Note, that the data is periodic in nature, like time of a day, so left and right sides of the plots above correspond to the same value.

Basically I need to detect peaks (= modes?) here (parameters like location and spread are important), together with some measure of their significance: i.e. the left plot looks like having two significant peaks, the right one has one and maybe far less significant other, and sometimes the data looks almost uniform - so, no peaks.

And now I'm not sure which method to take among those I know about, or maybe something else entirely? I wouldn't like to use histograms or KDE for this reason as they have parameters themselves and always lose some information.

The first thing I tried is gaussian mixture models - as I found no libraries supporting periodic data out-of-the-box, I just repeated my values a couple of time with corresponding shifts to see the result. So, it performs well with large peaks and much worse with closer-to-uniform data, as expected. Also, they don't easily get significance, but I guess one can use weights of peaks for this...

Another option may be just fitting empirical CDF with CDF of a uniform distribution plus zero/one/two wrapped gaussians, but surprisingly I didn't find much information on fitting CDFs - so, is this approach used at all?

As I found no ready to use library supporting my kind of data and models and so can't try different methods easily, I would like to know best or just good methods to try, probably I'll have to implement them myself.

Thanks!

Comment: It might be useful to look into the Non-Negative Trigonometric sum framework: There is an R package available, it fits a general class of distributions, and you may then choose the modality as a result of the output. I doubt, however, it would correctly pick out uniform data, so you would have to settle on some decision criterion there.

Comment: You don't actually "lose information" with a KDE: in principle, anyway, the KDE can be deconvolved back into the original data.  What you need, regardless of the methodology, is a suitable way to *smooth* the data, for otherwise "peak" is an ill-defined concept.  Any method of smoothing 1D data can readily be adapted to smoothing circular data.  (A quick and dirty way is to create additional copies of your data translated according to the period, smooth that, and restrict the smooth to one period.)